# Android list all applications that have permission to the camera

Tags: android, security, permissions

Could you please tell me How I can list all the applications which has permission to use the camera in an Android phone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know precisely what you mean by "has access to the camera".

You can use `PackageManager` to iterate over all installed packages via `getInstalledPackages()`. From there, you can see which ones have the `CAMERA` permission via the `requestedPermissions` field in the `PackageInfo` objects that you get from `getInstalledPackages()`.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare I was exactly looking for that